# SqlConnection, I'm using SQL Server, not LocalDB; so how to

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

So, in the tutorial I was checking, he uses a Database and connect it using this

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\RANBAH~1\Documents\testlogin.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
```

Although, I use SQL Server Management 17, which mean I have a server, So how do i get my SQL Connect Data Source? because afterward he uses it for

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select count(*) from login where username ='" + textBox1.Text + "' and password='" + textBox2.Text + "'", conn);
```

Any clue ?

Comment: I very strongly urge you to find better learning sources.  Anyone who glues data with strings to make SQL queries ought to be readiong - not writing - tutorials.  There are many, many good posts here on DB Access and of course MSDN

Answer (score 1):

Inside your project, in VS, connect to the server. Once you are on the server explorer, right click on the database to get the connection string. When you check the properties for the database, you should be able to see it. 
You cannot get the connection string from SSMS, though you can get all the information for the connection string. Then, you can use those information to create your own connection string using this website: https://www.connectionstrings.com/ Just check which is better suited for you.